# Control surface id in svg while knitting

Tags: r, svg, knitr

I've created a knitr document with `svg` figures to track any visual changes from commit to commit. The main problem I'm encountering is that changing the order of charts changes the .svg files' ids.

For example, consider the following weave:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<knitropts>>=
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "svg-differ/",
               dev = c("svg", "pdf"),
               fig.ext = c("svg", "pdf"))
set.seed(1)
@

<<chart>>=
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000)
y <- -2 * sin(10 * x) + 3 * x^2 - 2 * x
qplot(x, y, geom = "smooth")
@

<<chart-2>>=
x <- sample(seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000))
y <- -2 * sin(10 * x) + 3 * x^2 - 2 * x
qplot(x, y, geom = "smooth")
@

\end{document}
```

If I switch the order of the `chart` and `chart-2` chunks, the .svg files are identical except for one line:

`<g id="surface1">` and `<g id="surface6">`

Is there a way to make `svg` files so created to be (completely) identical up to reordering of the chunks? I understand the sequential ordering of these ids is important if multiple svgs are to be included in the same HTML file, but for my purpose this is not important.

Answer (score 1):

I think the id is set at a fairly low level in the `svg()` driver in R, and there's no obvious way to change it.  However, you could change it after producing the figure using a plot hook.  For example, put this in your knitr options chunk in your document:

```
<<knitropts>>=
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "svg-differ/",
               dev = c("svg", "pdf"),
               fig.ext = c("svg", "pdf"))
set.seed(1)
oldhook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot")
newhook <- function(x, options) {
  lines <- readLines(x)
  lines <- sub('<g id="surface[[:digit:]]+">',
      '<g id="surface">', lines)
  writeLines(lines, x)
  oldhook(x, options)
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = newhook)
@
```

This changes all strings like `<g id="surface##">` to simply `<g id="surface">` in the plot output file.  You'll probably want to make it a little more sophisticated; it should only try to do things to svg files, for instance, and it might be that some other id would be better.